# Centos kdump hangs up

Tags: centos, centos6, kdump

Trying kdump on CentOS 6.3.

On VMWare everything is fine and on oops crash kernel is loaded and vmcore created.

On phisical machine I see oops message, but crash kernel is not started.

I used kexec to load kernel, kdump loads. I used "kexec --load" instead of "kexec --load-panic" as kdump does. After that I run "kexec -e" to load into new kernel.
On console I see message "Starting new kernel" forever.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to configure kdump the redhat way, then you don't need to use kexec at all. Everything is integrated into kdump deamon itself.

Simple steps.

1) Download and install corresponding kernel-debuginfo and kernel-debuginfo-common

2) yum install kexec-tools crash

3) edit the /etc/kdump.conf file . eg if you want to push the vmcore file to remote machine then add

```
net root@10.2.2.222
core_collector makedumpfile -d 31 -c
```

4) Add

```
crashkernel=256M@16M
```

in /etc/grub.conf in kernel command line option

5)reboot the machine/vm

6) Start the kdump server

```
service kdump start
```

It will create the dump kernel image to load when crash happens.

7) Now test it

```
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue when reserved area for crash kernel is small (I've used `crashkernel=64M`). Try to increase `crashkernel` value. It should be specified as kernel boot parameter in your favourite bootloader.